My husband drives his personal car for his job. He was struck by a tree yesterday. Would his employer be responsible for damages
My husband was driving in a remote area yesterday to visit a patient. Out of nowhere, a tree falls on the hood of the car and caused quite a bit of damage. The company pays $700 a month which is taxed for personal use of the car and they do not pay anything in addition for mileage. I am assuming the money is intended for wear and tear, maintenance, and insurance. He contacted them this morning and all they said was that they’re sorry for the accident, and there was no policy for reimbursement of our deductible. is his company legally responsible for this since he is at no-fault and he was out driving for his job?

Surely that $700/month from the company is intended to contribute towards the insurance for the vehicle (and presumably your husband has the appropriate insurance cover to be using it for work)?

Yes we have full coverage and that money contributes to the insurance.

I would agree that the $8,400 is reimbursement for the use of the car, which covers the "wear and tear" of the cover and other requires services (oil changes, brake changes, tired changes. I also assume that you write off the "wear and tear: of the vehicle on your personal taxes as well as reimbursement on the miles per IRS rules.

I don’t think my husband itemizes, but we might have to start doing that.  Specially since we are taxed on that $700 stipend and probably get about 550-ish a month.

We need a location to give a fully formed answer.

Nashville, Tennessee

Insurance on the car is what should pay for the damages to the car, that is what it is for. If you only have 3rd party insurance (that covers damages to other parties), then you have chosen to take upon yourself the responsibility of any damages unless you can find another party at fault.

Paying for 3rd party insurance is admission of this responsibility. You can't say "oh I didn't know".

In this case if you are driving the car and there is no other party directly "at fault" then the driver is themselves at fault. It is a very tenuous claim that your employer forced you to drive your car to a specific destination, via a specific route on this day putting them at fault.

Some insurance providers have "No fault" and "Act of God" type clauses in their policies that might cover this scenario, if you are posting here I presume that you have already investigated this.


Yes we have full coverage

If you have fully comprehensive insurance that covers this damage and you are simply trying to avoid paying an excess or "at fault" claim fee, then just pay the fee, if it's less than the damage, then you win, the insurance has paid for itself! (If it is more than the damage, then pay for the repair and adjust your insurance so this isn't a problem in the future.)
Your insurance provider would normally exercise this next option on your behalf if the amount was significant, but if you really need to do this on your own because you are choosing not to use your insurance for the reason that you purchased it in the first place...
Instead of chasing the employer, you might choose to investigate negligence in care and maintenance of the tree and choose to sue who ever has custodianship over the land or property that the tree was or may still partially be on. A tree close enough to a road to fall on vehicles often falls under the responsibility of the road authority, as it is their responsibility to maintain road safety and one could argue the road is unsafe if a tree can fall on it.
I don't like to encourage litigation in these matters, but it is the only way to notify the other party that you think it is their responsibility to pay for your damages. If it was a corporate or public entity that has responsibility for the tree, then they should have their own insurance to settle these matters.

Honestly this sounds like a terrible deal.  Given the average car payment is in excess of $500 per month that leaves less than $200 a month for taxes, gas, and maintenance.  Even if the monies were tax free, if he drives more than 1,044 miles per month then is he is receiving less than the IRS allowable rate.
So the question is why would he agree to such?
Given that this company is stingy for car allowance why would you think they agree to covering the damage or deductible?
Baring a line item in a contract that says they are responsible for at fault damage there would seem to be no legal basis for such.  More than likely your husband signed a form that all liability for his driving is his own.

I should’ve added in there they cover the gas. We do not have a car payment on the car that he drives, but he’s put quite a bit of miles on there since he’s worked for this company for four months. We are both nurses and he is trying something different outside of the hospital.  I will see if he signed something concerning liability but basically they just said sorry about your accident.  Thanks for the input

If the $700/month from the employer was intended as "use this money to go out and buy and maintain a vehicle to use for work", then sure it does seem stingy. But my interpretation is that $700/month is compensation for the OP to use the vehicle they already have and would be paying for and maintaining anyway - it's intended to cover that additional expenses of using the vehicle for work, not the entire expense of owning the vehicle.
